# How do I stop Team Explorer Everywhere from seeing a deleted folder as a detected change

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

I am using Team Explorer Everywhere for 2012 command line

I issued a `tf get` but forgot the item spec so it got a couple of projects I didn't want before I noticed and hit Ctrl-c.

I did an `rm -rf` on those folders.

Now, when I do `tf status` it says:

```
 ----------------------------------
 Detected Changes:
 ----------------------------------
 File name Change Local path
 --------- ------ -----------------
 $/        
 PROJECT   delete /tfs/PROJECT
```

If I issue a `tf undo $/PROJECT`, it says that there are no changes to undo.

How do I stop TF from seeing this as a change -- I don't want to accidentally checkin the delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete an item that Team Foundation Version Control expects to exist on-disk, it detects that deletion and displays that as a "detected change".  Note that this is merely an informational message.  It is *not* a "pending change" and it cannot be undone, nor can it be checked in to the server, at least not without promoting the detected change to a pending change via a call to `tf delete`.

However, if you're worried about accidentally promoting that change, or if you're just tired of seeing it, you can instruct the client that you *shouldn't* have those in the first place.  The easiest way to do this is to do a get on that path of a previous version that didn't have these files, namely changeset 1:

```
tf get /version:C1 $/PROJECT
```

Now your local working folders are in sync with your workspace mappings and there should be no more detected changes to `$/PROJECT`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better resource than the MSDN docs? I couldn't find anything good and the CLI docs are pretty light.

Comment: The docs for the TEE CLC are pretty light, since they are meant to document the differences between the TEE CLC and the Windows Command-Line Client.  The Windows Command-Line Client documentation should be more fulfilling:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=vs.100).aspx